# Size property of new TextBox class multiplies by 1,5

Tags: c#, winforms, class, textbox

I have created a class for my own type of TextBox called TextBoxUnderline. The class inherits System.Windows.Forms.TextBox. However, when I set the size of TextBoxUnderline it resizes to 1.5 times the size when I add it in the designerview. For instance, if I set Size = new Size(100,100); and add it in designerview, TextBoxUnderline gets size 150,150.

Though, if I set MaximumSize = Size(100,100); it works well. TextBoxUnderline gets the size 100,100. However, I don't want to default MaximumSize as true.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace XYZ
{
    class TextBoxUnderline : TextBox
    {
        public TextBoxUnderline()
        {
            this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            this.AutoSize = false;
            this.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
            this.Size = new Size(200, 200);
            //this.MaximumSize = new Size(200, 200);


            this.MouseEnter += TextBoxUnderline_MouseEnter;
            this.MouseLeave += TextBoxUnderline_MouseLeave;
            this.GotFocus += TextBoxUnderline_GotFocus;
            this.LostFocus += TextBoxUnderline_LostFocus;

            this.Controls.Add(new Label()
            { Height = 1, Dock = DockStyle.Bottom, BackColor = Color.Black });
        }

        void TextBoxUnderline_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (((TextBoxUnderline)sender).Focused == false)
            {
                ((TextBoxUnderline)sender).BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
            }
        }

        void TextBoxUnderline_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((TextBoxUnderline)sender).BackColor = Color.White;
        }

        private void TextBoxUnderline_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((TextBoxUnderline)sender).BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        }

        private void TextBoxUnderline_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((TextBoxUnderline)sender).BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your display scaling set to 150% in the Windows settings?

Comment: Are you designing at 100% scale? Visual Studio issues a warning when you don't. -- If your Forms scale to Font, this will happen anyway, though. When you find a machine that scales the Font like that, that is.

Comment: My display scaling is set to 150 % due to i'm developing on a 13" for a 24" screen (long story short: company safety protocols makes it a nightmare to develop on our computers, I prefer using my personal computer).

This solved it! Can you please answer as a solution so that I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your display scaling is set to 150% in the Windows settings. You'll need to set that to 100% if you want the pixels on your screen to match the size you've set in your code.